# Javascript - find all possible strings

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Looking for some tips to solve this problem. We have string chain

> `const str = "543163431154"`,

and array with numbers where elements are basically numbers taken from this string

> `const array = ["21154", "543123", "163421154"]`

What I'm looking for is to find all possible strings

Was thinking to split our input string as first, then create variable to store single letters. Subsequently I could iterate over newly created array in some kind of reduce function, but tbh I have no right solution

Comment: As a hint I'd first come up with a naive recursive solution. Assuming that the some `elm` in `array` matches the current index `idx` in `str`, so that `str[idx:idx + len(elm)]` equals `elm`, can we take advantage of solving the subproblem of `str[idx + len(elm):]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: After a bit more reading I understood the problem a bit better, and boy was this fun!

```js
const str = "14316342115414321154"
const array = ["21154", "143", "21154143", "1634", "163421154"]

const findAllCombinations = (str, match) => {
    const result = match.reduce((acc, layer) => {
    if(str.indexOf(layer) === 0) {
      if(str.substring(layer.length).length > 0) {
        const nextLayer = findAllCombinations(str.substring(layer.length), match).map(c => addToLayer(layer, c))
            acc.push(...nextLayer)
      } else {
        acc.push(addToLayer(layer, ""))
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
  return result
}

const addToLayer = (layer, add) => `:${layer}${add}`

console.log(findAllCombinations(str,array))
```

Comment: well, unfortunately not, because as input we have `14316342115414321154` string and the array. Output array is something I need to get

Comment: ohh I get it, interesting problem!

Comment: @Caesars667 I included a solution proposal in my answer :)

Comment: There's most likely some edge cases in which it won't work properly, but that's up to you to. Happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an algorithm,

- From your array, create 5 arrays, each one with different order of the elements from the original array
- Iterate over each array
- For each element, check using regex if the `str` starts with it (`^currentElement`)
- If it is, remove from your `str` the current element and continue to the next element
- If it's not, continue to the next array from the 5 you created
- If you reach the last index of every array and `str` starts with it, add the current array to the results.

Here you go, now because it's not a code writing site and it's  not a specific code question I wont write it for you - but the above algorithm will work for you.

Comment: What is this first step? Sounds unnecessarily complex and prone to errors.

Comment: It's better to think string as a tree, which we can traverse layer by layer as in my solution.